# Retrieving specific object *image* from user profile to display on frontend

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am trying to query set a specific image from the Django user. My goal is to let each image have it's own page, when you click on the image from the profile page it should send you to another page with that same photo and just the photo you clicked, the page that I have already done has all the photos in order from when you posted them, I have looked through the documentation of Django 3.0 and I cannot find a query set function that allows me to get the specific image from a specific user for the function **single page in views.py**. All my other functions work, just wanted to show them just in case yall needed to reference to my other views.py functions. If anyone could guide me a little that would be great.

My images are stored in AWS S3 and maybe there is a way to retieve that url as source.

views.py

```
def profile(request, user):
    img = Uploads.objects.filter(profile_id = request.user.profile)
    profile = Profile.objects.filter(user = request.user)
    context = {"profile": profile, "img": img}

    return render(request, "main/profile.html", context)


def profile_uploads(request):
    profile = request.user.profile
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = Uploads_Form(data = request.POST, files = request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.profile = request.user.profile
            form.save()
            obj = form.instance
            return redirect('/profile/<str:user>/')
    else:
        form = Uploads_Form()
    img = Uploads.objects.all()
    return render(request,"main/profile_uploads.html", {"img":img, "form":form})


def single_page(request, user):
    img = Uploads.objects.filter(file = request.user.profile)
    context = {"img": img}
    return render(request, 'main/single_page.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to serve and save media files (images, files), you are welcome to

[Django's Managing files documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/files/)

You have to set `MEDIA_URL` and `MEDIA_ROOT` settings

Then you have to define an ImageField inside your model like so:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="my_model/images")
    ...
```

To get the url of an image use

```
my_model_instance = MyModel.objects.get(...)
url = my_model_instance.image.url
```

To display an image in html

```
...
<img src="{{ my_model_instance.image.url }}"/>
...
```

Comment: Thank you man, but I already did all that, I think my issue is in the objects.filter.

Comment: Do all objects inside the modal have a id, that maybe I could retrieve?